# Reduce row height / margins in Datatable?

Tags: html, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I'm using a datatable in a shiny app with custom coloring of the cells. This is done in html (each cell is a `div`) and by telling DT to not escape these specific columns.

It looks like this with DT :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSzRv.jpg)

My issue is that I would like the coloring to take the entire height of each cell so that there is no margins. If I could have the different cell colors to touch each other that would be great.

I have try to add `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` but it makes no difference.

I've also tried to use the `formatstyle` from `DT` to reduce the row height like so :
`formatStyle( 0, target = 'row', lineHeight = '80%')`
and the result looks like this :
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3WQl.jpg)

I'm currently trying with `padding: 0px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;` but it does not work any better.
It looks to me that this is a margin from `DT` rather than my `div` since whatever I try in my div style, I've always the same margins between the colors and the row height limits. The only thing is I do not know how to control it.

Would anyone know how to achieve such a result ?
Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Code used :

```
for (c in colnames(ranking)[10:13]) {
      ranking <- ranking %>%
        filter(param %in% input$param) %>%
        arrange_(.dots = c) %>%
        mutate(!!paste0(c, "_rk") := 1:nrow(ranking %>% filter(param %in% input$param)))
      tmp <- ranking %>%
        arrange_(.dots = c) %>%
        select_(.dots = c)

      max <- tmp %>% tidyr::drop_na() %>% .[, 1] %>% max()
      min <- tmp %>% tidyr::drop_na() %>% .[, 1] %>% min()
      range <- max - min
      brks <- vector(length = colors)

      for (i in 1:colors) {
        brks[i] <- i^pracma::bisect(function(x) range^(1/x) - (colors + 1), 1, 5)$root %>% round(2) + min - 2
      }

      tmp <- tmp %>% 
        mutate(brks = ifelse(is.na(tmp[, 1]),
                             NA,
                             cut(tmp %>% tidyr::drop_na() %>% .[, 1], brks)))
      colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("#c31432", "#ffc500", "#edde5d", "white"))
      clrs <- colfunc(colors + 1)

      tmp_nrow <- tmp %>% nrow()

      for (i in 1:tmp_nrow) {
        row <- which(tmp[i, 1] == ranking[,c])

        r <- clrs[tmp[i, 2]] %>% col2rgb() %>% .[1]
        g <- clrs[tmp[i, 2]] %>% col2rgb() %>% .[2]
        b <- clrs[tmp[i, 2]] %>% col2rgb() %>% .[3]

        tmp[i, 1] <- paste0("<center><div style='background: ", "radial-gradient(rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "0), rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "0.25), rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "1)", ")", "; border: solid 0px;font-family: \"Interstate Black\";font-weight: bolder;padding: 0;margin: 0;'>",
                            tmp[i, 1],
                            "</div></center>")

        ranking[row,paste0(c, "_coloring")] <- tmp[i, 1]
      }
    }

        ranking_m <- as.matrix(ranking %>%
                             filter(param %in% input$param) %>%
                             select(4, 47, 40, 38, 31, 32, 41, 42, 43, 44))

    DT::datatable(ranking_m,
                  escape = c(TRUE, FALSE, rep(FALSE, 8)),
                  filter = 'top',
                  extensions = list('Responsive' = NULL),
                  options = list(pageLength = 25,
                                 lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100),
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '400px', targets = 0),
                                                   list(width = '25px', targets = 1),
                                                   list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 2:9)))) #%>%
      # formatStyle( 0, target = 'row', lineHeight = '80%')
```

Comment: Do you specifically need to use datatable for this? There are other packages that could do this.

Comment: I moved from `htmlTableWidget` to DT so I can only use `DT` when it comes to tables, along with filtering and sorting which is great.
Typically I haven't had this margin issue with `htmlTableWidget`, but no sorting nor filtering was possible.
What package do you have in mind ?

Comment: How did you set the colors ? Can you provide your code ?

Comment: It's mainly a radial gradient with custom colors all in the style of the div. It looks like something like this :
`paste0("<center><div style='background: ", "radial-gradient(rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "0), rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "0.25), rgba(", r, ",", g, ",", b, ",", "1)", ")", "; border: solid 0px;font-family: \"Interstate Black\";font-weight: bolder;padding: 0px;margin:0px;'>",
                            tmp[i, 1],
                            "</div></center>")`

`tmp[i,1]` being the numbers displayed in each cell.

Comment: I was thinking about `tableHTML` and the function `add_css_conditional_column`. You have complete control over the colouring (to do the ranking exactly as you want - the colours span across the whole cell), but it misses the JS functionality of sorting and filtering. If the sorting / filtering is not an issue, I can show you an example

Comment: From what you say it seems pretty similar to what I had with `htmlTableWidget` but it lacks sorting and filtering as well, which is a very good feature. Thanks anyway for the suggestion :)

Comment: @homer3018 You have to set this CSS to the cells (`td`), not to the cells content. Please provide a code so that I can help you.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ok great but I'm not sure what code exactly you'd like to see. Could you please be more specific ?
Also I've read that the formatStyle function accept any CSS properties so maybe it can be done from there ?

Comment: @homer3018 Yes, `formatStyle` is a possibility. But I have to see how you conditionally define the colors (I don't know what are `r`, `g`, `b` and `i` in the code you posted in a comment). Please provide a code that generates your table.

Comment: I see. Let try to explain first what these are then : I go column per column, then define some breaks to compute a ramp palette. From there I can define breaks and hence `r`,`g`,`b` value. Column is sorted the way I want, and I go line by line to change the value from `tmp[i,1]` to what you've seen. so `i` is the row number. I'll be able to share some more code but before I need to make it more like a minimal example. It might not be efficient but it works in my case.
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I have found this : https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator but it does not expose the cell margin or padding.
The more I think about it the more I think that it needs to be an enforced argument (so maybe in `formatStyle`) of the DT object, only I do not know how to write it properly.

Comment: Show your code ^^

Comment: lol ok. Edited the OP. Very last line commented with the `formatStyle`, this gives the second screenshot where it's all squashed horizontally. It could help further to display more rows on the screens but we have to get rid of that margin first.

Comment: Hmmm this is not a minimal code ^^ I will give a simple example. Wait.

Comment: and yet I trimmed it quite a bit.... but hey you asked for it ;)

Comment: Ok I think I can change it to put the gradient in the `formatStyle` as you did. Thanks ! I'll test and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background CSS must be set to the cells, not to the cells contents. This can be achieved with `formatStyle`. Here is an example with random colors:

```
library(DT)
dat <- iris[1:5,]
ncols <- ncol(dat)

# background for column 1
r <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
g <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
b <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
dat$RGB1 <- sprintf("radial-gradient(rgba(%s,%s,%s,0),rgba(%s,%s,%s,0.25),rgba(%s,%s,%s,1))", 
                   r, g, b, r, g, b, r, g, b)

# background for column 2
r <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
g <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
b <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
dat$RGB2 <- sprintf("radial-gradient(rgba(%s,%s,%s,0),rgba(%s,%s,%s,0.25),rgba(%s,%s,%s,1))", 
                    r, g, b, r, g, b, r, g, b)

# background for column 4
r <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
g <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
b <- sample.int(256, 5, replace = TRUE) - 1L
dat$RGB4 <- sprintf("radial-gradient(rgba(%s,%s,%s,0),rgba(%s,%s,%s,0.25),rgba(%s,%s,%s,1))", 
                    r, g, b, r, g, b, r, g, b)

datatable(dat, 
          options = 
            list(
              columnDefs = 
                list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncols + 1:3),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = 1:ncols)
                )
            )) %>%
  formatStyle(1, valueColumns = ncols+1, background = JS("value")) %>%
  formatStyle(2, valueColumns = ncols+2, background = JS("value")) %>%
  formatStyle(4, valueColumns = ncols+3, background = JS("value")) %>%
  formatStyle(1:ncols, `font-family` = "Interstate Black") %>% 
  formatStyle(1:ncols, fontWeight = "bolder")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stéphane :) I'll test that on my own as it needs some tweaks so I can get it to work along with my existing code, but this looks like the answer :)

Comment: Just to report back that It works as expected. I've even added conditionnal formating in some of the `formatStyle` using `styleEqual`. At the end the code is easier to understand than before and the column types are now numeric (as it should) but it was character with my old code, not friendly with the filtering. Thanks again